# How to compile scala swing app?

Tags: scala, scala-swing

I'm using:

```
% scalac -version
Scala compiler version 2.9.1 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
```

on Ubuntu 12.04.

This code is saved in HelloGui.scala:

```
import scala.swing._

object HelloGui extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "Hello World GUI"
    contents = new Button {
      text = "Click me"
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to compile this I get:

```
% scalac HelloGui.scala        
HelloGui.scala:1: error: object swing is not a member of package scala
import scala.swing._
             ^
one error found
```

I've tried using `import swing._` (it isn't clear from the tutorials which import path I need to use with this version of scala), and I get:

```
% scalac HelloGui.scala
HelloGui.scala:1: error: not found: object swing
import swing._
       ^
one error found
```

When I look in /usr/share/java, I see scala-swing-2.9.1.jar and scala-swing.jar as a symlink to it, so it seems like the libraries are present?

Am I missing a compiler flag or is there another package I need to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler needs to have the path to the swing jar passed explicitly. This works:

```
% scalac -classpath /usr/share/java/scala-swing.jar HelloGui.scala
```